# Crash ios cordova app gracefully

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

This might sound odd but I want to get my app to crash gracefully.

Since there is no way in cordova to actually close the app via API this seems to be the only solution, well at least in my mind.

So my question how can I crash my cordova app without an error dialog popping up?

Or as an alternative: are there ways to close the app I don't know about?

Comment: if it is in iOS, why don't you do the crash part natively ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri because if you do it you will see a little warning window "App as crash". Not the best UX. I also cant find something like ".exit(0)"

Comment: As mentioned in the link from Shamas S, there is a reason for not being able to find this API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is considered against Apple policies to programmatically crash/close the app and is highly recommended not to do this. And Apple has rejected apps in the past, that don't adhere to this policy.

This is mentioned by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1561/_index.html), since an app that closes down albeit programmatically, gives user the illusion of a crash which is not a good user experience.

It goes on to say,

> If during development or testing it is necessary to terminate your
>   application, the abort function, or assert macro is recommended.

Comment: To be more specific, my client wants a button to close the app.

Comment: @Silom. Share the exact same link with them. Usually people want to close the app if user doesn't agree to terms and conditions. At which, just show an alert telling them they have to agree to terms and conditions in order to continue using the app.

Comment: In my case the user is mend to wait until some service worker got his request done -> "Hello user, close the app and come again" -> "User will use the meaningful and magnificent exit button instead of the physical one"

Comment: @Silom That is still pretty stupid. Instead display an alert, without a button, asking them to come back later. If it's an enterprise app i.e it won't be published to AppStore, you can just perform a failing assert.

Comment: Alright, this is a very helpful reason. That way I can talk it out of the scope. Thanks for your affords. It didn't solve the question but at least the situation. Do you mind updating your question regarding the ios app policies? This would make it a valid answer I guess. And of cause it is stupid but as a developer you are kind of "end of the line" if it comes to design. Well, I wish you a nice day and I will vote your answer after you updated it.

Comment: @Silom updated the answer. You have a great day too :)